# What is the difference between the two python statements?

Tags: python

Please explain the meaning of the two statements:

`obj = ClassName` and 
`obj = ClassName()`

Comment: In what context do you want them explained? Tip: If you can answer that, you've essentially answered your own question. And don't simply say "what's the difference". What have you observed the difference to be, and what don't you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ClassName` is a reference to the class. `Classname()` instantiates an object of that class.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is a first class object in Python.

`ClassName` will return a reference to the type `ClassName` and `ClassName()` calls the `__init__()` method of class `ClassName`.

If you are familiar with Java, then `ClassName()` calls the constructor.

For example:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self,lat,long):
        self.lat = lat
        self.long = long
p = Point(10.1,12.2)`

p
Out[37]: <__main__.Point at 0x1118585c0>`
```